# Missing leading slash on images uploaded with Django Filebrowser

Tags: python, django, file-browser, django-filebrowser

I'm having an issue with Django-Filebrowser when I try to upload an image. I'm using the following versions: **Django 1.8.7**, **Filebrowser 3.6.4** and **Python 2.7**.

When I try to upload an image, everything works as expected, and the uploaded files are placed in the right folder without any problem; but the resultant file url doesn't have any leading slash necessary to serve properly the file.

For example, if I try to upload "test.jpg", the final image url will be "uploads/test.jpg" and "_versions/test_xxx.jpg" that actually creates issues even in the Filebrowser panel, since the resulting request will be issued to `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/uploads/test.jpg` and `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/_versions/test.jpg` rather than `http://localhost:8000/uploads/test.jpg` and `http://localhost:8000/_versions/test.jpg` that the server would serve properly.

(Note that the Filebrowser panel url is `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/`)

Here's my settings:

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('articles.urls')),

    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'uploads/'
FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS_BASEDIR = '_versions/'
```

Add a leading slash to the `FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY` would trigger a SouspiciusFileOperation error since '/uploads/' is located outside the project folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got the point. It's enough to set explicitly `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Now Filebrowser will search for `"uploads/"` and `"_versions/"` folders in this new parent one, so `"/media"` needs to be served accordingly.